# Is it possible to edit updatesUrl variable value after installation of my application?

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to edit the updatesUrl variable value after installation of my application for our local testing purpose instead of production url for downloads.

Answer (score 0):

"sys.updatesUrl" is a compiler variable and cannot be updated after the compilation.

However, you can do the following:

1. Look for the "Check for update" action in your updater and replace the value `${compiler:sys.updatesUrl}` in the "Update descriptor URL" property with an installer variable, say `${installer:myUpdatesUrl}`.
2. On the "Installer->Screens & Actions step", select the installer node, activate the "Installer variables" tab, click on "Configure predefined installer variables" and add the variable "myUpdatesUrl" with a string value of `${compiler:sys.updatesUrl}`. On the "Response file tab" for the variable, select the "Write to response file" check box.
3. Add a "Load a response file" action to the "Startup" node of the updater with the default property values.

Then, you can modify the installer variable "myUpdatesUrl" in the installer and the updater will use that value.

---

**Update 2019-02-07**

Starting with install4j 8, the default value of the "Update descriptor URL" property of the "Check for update" action will be `${installer:updatesUrl?:${compiler:sys.updatesUrl}}` making use of the new default syntax for missing variables, so that the command line argument

```
-VupdatesUrl=<URL>
```

to the update downloader will always override the URL entered on the "Installer->Auto-Update Options" step.